# Subscription based restrictions for rails queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rather complex issue that I could some assistance with, as all implementations I've been trying are flawed (Rails 4.2.1).

Users have access to devices:

```
create_table "devices", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "device_guid"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "user_ids"
end
```

and devices have many data entries:

```
create_table "datas", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "device_id"
  t.datetime "start_time"
  t.datetime "end_time"
end
```

We want to restrict **all** queries to the data based on Subscriptions.

```
create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "device_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "start_date"
  t.datetime "end_date"
end
```

So effectively, data should not be accessed unless Subscriptions allows it.

I wanted to have this restriction done in one place (not by individual method to access it), so other people writing code still deal with the subscription restriction. I don't want to use a 3rd party gem as the data is very sensitive.

I thought the most obvious way to do this would be set a default_scope on the Data model, but I ran into several problems:
**1)** You can't access @user from the Data model. I got around this with an ugly hack to access User.current from the model.
**2)** I can't use current_user since we have admins that pose as other users, and need to see the data as they would. Used the same workaround as #1
**3)** There can be multiple subscriptions with different dates for the same user and device. There isn't any way to do an ActiveRecord Query that I know of that can account for two separate date ranges (I got around this by using arel_table).
**4)** This makes all of the methods written that query the data to fail when I'm in the rails console (and theoretically through an API interface). I got around this by ignoring the default scope if there is no User.current, but obviously that's a security concern.

This is my current implementation (in psuedocode):

```
query = []
Subscription.each do |s|
  if (User.current.id == s.user_id)
    temp = Data.all.where(data[:start_time] >= s.start_date).where(data[:end_time] <= s.end_date).where(data[:device_id] == Device.find_by(id: s.device_id).device_guid)
    end
  end
  query += temp
end
default_scope { query }
```

I put this code just directly into the model. I didn't think it would work, but it does... sometimes. It acts oddly, sometimes completely restricting a user when it shouldn't, although it hasn't (yet) given somebody access to data they should not have.

I'm looking to redesign this from the ground up, and do it the best way. I'm open to any suggestions (except 3rd-party, sorry) on how best to approach it. I don't mind if it takes a lot of work to implement, I'd rather do it right this time. Any account for expandability (such as if we implemented an API for remote queries) would be a great feature as well, though we don't currently need it.

Just to reiterate, I insist that this restriction be "automatic" to all queries, so that if a front coder for instance writes:

```
<%= @user.device.find(1).data.all.count %>
```

in a view, it won't show any data the user doesn't have a subscription for.

Thanks for any suggestions. Sorry for the long wall of text, this has been a rather perplexing problem.

Comment: `datas.device_id` should probably be an integer an integer. Don't do authorization on the model level. I'm not trying to be contrarian here but do you really think your homemade solution is going to be more secure than battle tested authorization solutions like CanCan or Pundit? Smells like Not Invented Here syndrome.

Comment: Basically the reason why you should not do it on the model level is that models should not be aware of the application environment such as the session. It leads to horrible convoluted code. Instead you can do what Pundit does and use a Policy class which takes a model or scope to be authorized and a user and returns true / false (or raises an exception).

Comment: @max I understand that this seems like Not Invented Here, but I use a ton of gems, it is just security specific ones we are looking to rewrite. Which would just be this, and devise. I love gems and use a ton, but this isn't my call, and personally I agree with it for this specific case, this data is really sensitive. Could you give a bit more information about the Policy class in an answer? If I go that route I'll select it as the right answer - thanks for the advice.